# How do I Bind a WPF Ellipse's Height to its own Width?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textblock, ellipse

I have an ellipse drawn inside a Grid.Row and Grid.Column.  The Row is always taller than the Column is wide.

I want to draw an ellipse that fills the width of the grid column and who's height makes it a perfect circle.

I also want to draw a single digit number exactly in the center of the above ellipse.  Basically ending up with a circle that has a number centered inside it.

I can easily set HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" on my Ellipse and on the TextBlock containing the number.  This takes care of the width for me.  However, how do I get the Height of the Ellipse and TextBlock to always match its Width, even when the Grid.Column width changes?

Here's some XAML to illustrate this.  In the XAML below, I want the hard coded '63' to be based on the Grid.Column width, or the Width feild of the ellipse:

```
    <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="63" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="63" Height="63" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="1" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="42" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Thanks for all your help.  I ended up using Herdo's answer.  Just set HorizontalAlignment to Stretch and then bind the height to the actual width of the ellipse.  I did this same thing to the ellipse and to the text block:

```
    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: Putting the Ellipse and the TextBlock into a common Grid would also solve the text centering problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Grid` containing the Ellipse, you can use the `ActualWidth` property, and keeping it stretched, without setting the `Width` property - allowing you to use the Ellipse without any reference to the parent container:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <!-- Or whatever width -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Please take into account the remarks for the `ActualWidth` property on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Because ActualWidth is a calculated value, you should be aware that
>   there could be multiple or incremental reported changes to it as a
>   result of various operations by the layout system. The layout system
>   may be calculating required measure space for child elements,
>   constraints by the parent element, and so on.

Therefore, the following example code...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             Fill="Red"
             Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Grid>
```

...will result into this behavior (the width/height would update every time, the container - the `Grid` in this case - changes its layout):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any bindings. Put a Path with a circular `EllipseGeometry` and `Stretch="Uniform"` into a common inner Grid, which you then place into your outer Grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="42" FontWeight="Bold" Text="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the Height of the Ellipse to the grid column width like this :

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=ColumnDefinitions[0].Width.Value}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have skipped unimportant attributes

```
<Ellipse x:Name="El" Width="50" Height="{Binding ElementName=El,Path=ActualWidth}"/>
<TextBlock Height="{Binding ElementName=El,Path=ActualWidth}"/>
```

Comment: This works, but the Width is hard coded to "50".  I have this Ellipse and the TextBlock inside a column in a grid, and the column changes size based on the width of the window.  It can probably fluctuate between 30-70 depending on how much the main app window is stretched by the user.  I need the Ellipse Width to be based on the width of the grid.column that contains it.

Comment: so, just remove hardcoded width and set horizontalalignment=stretch